# Zoom Q2HD for podcast-quality recordings?

Tags: microphone, voice, filter, microphone-positioning, podcasts

I happen to already own a Zoom Q2HD.  I have used it to record meetings and music auditions and have been happy with the results.

Now I wonder if I could use it to record an individual voice.  I am not making a podcast, but for the purposes of my question, let's think in those terms.  Would my Zoom give good enough quality?  (I don't mean one of those awful let's-record-ourselves-having-a-conversation podcast, but a good quality podcast such as *The Longest Shortest Time*, *Decoder Ring Theater* or *Radio Diaries*.

What is the best distance and angle to get good sound quality and minimize popping and too much sibilance?  Do I need a pop filter?  If so, can I make one?  I read that you can put a stocking over a coat hanger.  What would be the right distance from the Zoom?

Are there any particular settings I should choose for the Zoom before starting?

I have a little desk tripod that the Zoom screws onto.

Does it matter whether the speaker sits or stands?

Is it okay to record in the living room?  It has a cathedral ceiling but is has plenty of books and other clutter, so I don't think there's echo.  It is quiet as long as I move the battery operated wall clock out of the room, and as long as the cat doesn't announce an urgent need to go out.  I can let the cat out before hitting Record.

I read that I should use earbuds in the Zoom's earphone jack to monitor the sound while recording.  I suppose this would allow me to adjust the levels as necessary, in case the speaker adjusts his distance from the mic, or just gets excited and starts talking louder?

Any other tips?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get great quality with your zoom device, and it will all come down to the room. So I think the living room is probably out of the question, but you can try it.

To get a professional sound, you want to sound like a radio broadcast, and they do not have any room reverberation. I suggest you record in a dead space with no reverberation.

But really what I think would be best is to dampen the space. So have a small room with acoustic treatment on the walls. But that is probably overkill for your case.

You could use something like this around the zoom...

[https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-602650-Microphone-Isolation-Shield/dp/B00GR9W1MS/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1487719196&sr=8-2&keywords=microphone+shield](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GR9W1MS)

OR....

take a cardboard box, maybe about 24" x 24", and line it with fiberglass insulation, and mount the mix deep inside there (hang it from fishing line?). And then talk into the "dead box". That is what I would do.